# Common Lisp: Optimizing functions in SBCL

Tags: common-lisp

For 2D graphics I need to optimize my functions, but in SBCL I get lots of comments about SBCL not being able to inline arithmetic operations. I tried all sorts of declarations but it doesn't seem to make the compiler happy. Here is a simple example:

```
(defun test-floor (x div)
  (declare (type single-float x)
           (type (signed-byte 64) div)
           (optimize (speed 3)))
  (floor x div))
```

gives the following 4 notes below. I'm completely lost as #'floor is a builtin function. I tried to find information/tutorials on how to properly give the compiler hints in SBCL and didn't find the right information, so any info would be very appreciated! Unfortunately optimization in Common Lisp is quite unknown territory for me. I'm using SBCL 1.3.20 on a Linux machine.

```
; file: /tmp/file595dqU
; in: defun test-floor
;     (FLOOR CL-FLOCKS::X CL-FLOCKS::DIV)
; --> MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND MULTIPLE-VALUE-CALL TRUNCATE LET* 
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:%UNARY-TRUNCATE/SINGLE-FLOAT (/ SB-C::X SB-C::F))
; 
; note: forced to do full call
;       unable to do inline float truncate (cost 5) because:
;       The result is a (values integer &optional), not a (values
;                                                          (signed-byte 64) &rest
;                                                          t).

; --> MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND MULTIPLE-VALUE-CALL TRUNCATE LET* VALUES - * 
; ==>
;   (SB-KERNEL:%SINGLE-FLOAT SB-C::RES)
; 
; note: forced to do full call
;       unable to do inline float coercion (cost 5) because:
;       The first argument is a integer, not a (signed-byte 64).

; --> MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND MULTIPLE-VALUE-CALL FUNCTION IF VALUES 1- 
; ==>
;   (- SB-C::TRU 1)
; 
; note: forced to do generic-- (cost 10)
;       unable to do inline fixnum arithmetic (cost 1) because:
;       The first argument is a integer, not a fixnum.
;       The result is a (values integer &optional), not a (values fixnum &rest t).
;       unable to do inline fixnum arithmetic (cost 2) because:
;       The first argument is a integer, not a fixnum.
;       The result is a (values integer &optional), not a (values fixnum &rest t).
;       etc.

; --> MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND MULTIPLE-VALUE-CALL FUNCTION IF VALUES 
; ==>
;   (+ REM SB-C::DIVISOR)
; 
; note: doing signed word to integer coercion (cost 20) from div, for:
;       the second argument of generic-+
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   printed 4 notes

CL-USER>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `floor`, you have to deal with different subtypes of numbers: the code divides a float by an integer (that may involve coercing the integer as a float), and then have to coerce the result back to an integer. This is the amount of work that must be done, correctly, and you are unlikely to bypass it if you don't restrict your input types.

If instead you use [`ffloor`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_floorc.htm), then the primary result is a float (you can still round it to an integer later,  when you really need it (e.g. convert to pixels coordinates)). The following code does not give compilation notes:

```
(defun test-floor (x div)
  (declare (type single-float x)
           (type fixnum div)
           (optimize (speed 3)))
  (ffloor x div))
```

You may even declare `div` as being a `float`, which would push the responsibility of providing appropriately typed values (and performing runtime checks) to the callers.

Note also that you should probably `(declaim (inline test-floor))` before you define the function; that helps because then the compiler can put shortcuts in the code to avoid checking input parameter types and boxing results.

Edit:

The range of a float cover a large possible domain (due to the exponent): more densely packed near zero, more spaced towards infinity. Integer values are linearly spaced, but cover a smaller range with the same number of bits. So if you want to guarantee your output fits in a `fixnum`, you have to make sure the float in your inputs does not go outside the range of fixnum, too. I tried the following:

```
(defun test-round (x)
  (declare (type (single-float #.(float most-negative-fixnum 0f0)
                               #.(float (/ most-positive-fixnum 2) 0f0)) x)
           (optimize (speed 3)))
  (round x))
```

I had to half the upper range of the floats because when you test:

```
(typep (round (coerce most-positive-fixnum 'single-float)) 'fixnum)
```

... it returns NIL. I don't have much time to see why this happens, but this depends on your implementation and architecture. Taking half the most positive fixnum ensures the value is low enough to be converted as a fixnum. Now, I have no more compilation notes.

(the same goes for `(signed-byte 64)`))

*NB. Unlike in the above example, you should use `deftype` and avoid repeating the same declarations everywhere.*

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! As you assume correctly, I do a lot pixel calculations and the pixels are stored in arrays. But I haven't yet found a way to round floats without compiler complaints:

`(defun test-round (x)

      (declare (type single-float x)

               (optimize (speed 3)))

      (round x))`

Comment: The compiler complains that the result is an integer and not a (signed-byte 64). It would be nice if I could tell the compiler somehow that the value actually *is* within the 64 bit range.

Comment: The thing is: how do you know the result is in the 64 bits range? what should happen if this is not the case? SBCL tries really hard to prevent you from doing incorrect things. You should restrict the input float domain so that the result must be in the expected range (will edit)

Comment: I was thinking along these lines to restrict the input float domain as for the functions which need to be optimized all I'm doing is vector math within the screen resolution, so I can safely assume the input values are sane. I even consider doing everything with fixnum math and lookup tables for non-rational operations, but I'm not even sure if that's actually faster considering FP-units in current CPUs.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specify the return value of an expression you can use `THE`:

```
(the fixnum (1+ 3))
```

But you really want to make sure that the value is actually a fixnum. If you 'lie', then Lisp may believe you and you have unspecified runtime effects. SBCL may warn at compile time, but you really should take care of that. If you provide wrong types are return wrong types, data may get corrupted and/or Lisp may crash.

Another way to specify a return value is the `FTYPE` declaration:

For example a function `ith` may take an integer and a list as arguments. It returns an arbitrary type -> `T` or any subtype.

```
(declaim (ftype (function (integer list) t)
                ith))
```

For example:

```
(the fixnum (+ (the fixnum a) (the fixnum b)))
```

There you need to be sure that:

- a is an fixnum
- b is an fixnum
- the sum of a and b is also always a fixnum

Here this is easier, since the sum of a and b is definitely a fixnum:

```
CL-USER 3 > (let ((a 3) (b 12))
              (the fixnum (+ (the (integer 0 10) a)
                             (the (integer 3 20) b))))
15
```

Lisp may check that at runtime and/or compile-time. The addition now can be a simple fixnum operation and does not need to deal with fixnum overflows and bignums. If you set the `safety` value to something low, then the runtime check may also be omitted. But: you should never call this code with the wrong types.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful, too! Although in principle all that was clear, I just didn't know how to specify it in code and it seemed hard to find information on this topic. All these comments will definitely help getting a better understanding of optimization in CL/SBCL. Thanks to all for your time to help!

Answer (score 1):

SBCL is claiming that it can’t optimise the call to `floor` because it isn’t sure the return value will be small enough to fit into a 64-bit integer.

```
CL-USER> (test-floor 1f25 1234)
8103727629894569426944 ;
0.0
CL-USER> (format nil “~b” *)
;; a long binary string 
CL-USER> (length *)
73
```

A 73 bit Integer may be returned but does not fit into 64 bits.

Se also the SBCL manual:

- [4 Compiler](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Compiler)

  - [4.1.3 Understanding Compiler Diagnostics](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Understanding-Compiler-Diagnostics)
- [6 Efficiency](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Efficiency)

Edit: after some searching I have found the transformation for `floor`. It is [here](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/master/src/compiler/srctran.lisp#L3154-L3161). I reproduce it below:

```
(deftransform floor ((number divisor))
  `(multiple-value-bind (tru rem) (truncate number divisor)
     (if (and (not (zerop rem))
              (if (minusp divisor)
                  (plusp number)
                  (minusp number)))
         (values (1- tru) (+ rem divisor))
         (values tru rem))))
```

So that explains what the compiler messages were talking about

Comment: That seems very reasonable, thanks! Is there a way to tell the compiler that the result will never be beyond the 64 bit range? Or would it be more efficient to use ffloor as suggested in coredump's answer?

Comment: I’ve not found anything yet